# Why is there destructive interference in one path in Wheeler's delayed choice experiment?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons

In the diagram below I've drawn Wheeler's delayed choice experiment, in the case where a 2nd half-silvered mirror has been inserted near the detectors.

```
---->\-------->\
     |         |
     v         v
     \-------->\--> D2 (0%)
               |
               v
               D1 (100%)
```

Every summary of this experiment I've found says that in this case destructive interference will occur at D2 and constructive interference will occur at D1.

I understand why the two paths interfere constructively at D1:

- One path has 1 reflection => phase change of 180$^\circ$
- The other path has 3 reflections => phase change of 3 x 180$^\circ$ which equals 180$^\circ$ modulo 360$^\circ$

I don't understand why the two paths interfere destructively at D2:

- One path has 2 reflections
- The other path *also* has 2 reflections

Can anyone explain why interference is supposed to be destructive at D2?

Comment: I believe you drew the diagram wrong. D1 is getting some paths with one reflection and some with 3, so D1 should have the destructive interference and be 0%

Comment: Yes, given the answer you appear to be right. I copied the diagram and the intensity split from https://www.quantamagazine.org/closed-loophole-confirms-the-unreality-of-the-quantum-world-20180725/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For beam-splitters there is a phase difference of +- Pi/2 between transmitted an reflected beam. If you take that into account and the direction of the beam vs. splitter, everything seems fine.Look here: https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1509/1509.00393.pdf